# Google Chrome has rendering bug(Chrome 66)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My website has a div that's pretty tall(about 20000px height)
But Google Chrome stops rendering and chops it around 16000px, and anything below that is not rendered. Empty.
Whereas, Safari works(Safari rocks!). It can render all contents.

How can I fix this? Is there some kind of Max-number of divs that Chrome can render?

Comment: Please provide an example as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, also around 16000px.

My page has an animation to fade in the content after loading. That was the cause of the problem.
When I removed the animation from the div, specifically `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`, the page worked perfectly.

Comment: Omg thank you! I have some animation going on too! I'll apply ur fixes and see! thanks for the reply!!